# How can I use a function declared inside a Typescript class inside another function in that class?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this code:

```
class ExamPage {

  tabClear() {
    page.clear(this.examName);
    page.clear(this.examVersionId);
  }

  createNew() {
    describe('Create new' , function() {
      it('Clear input boxes', function() {
        tabClear(); // <<< not recognized 
      });
    });
  }

}
```

Can someone advise me.  I would like to call the function tabClear() but I cannot access it.  Can someone tell me how I can do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case we need to call function of our own class we always have to use **this**

```
class ExamPage {

  tabClear() {
    page.clear(this.examName);
    page.clear(this.examVersionId);
  }

  createNew() {
    describe('Create new' , function() { 
      it('Clear input boxes', function() {
        this.tabClear(); // HERE the this.tabClear() is the answer
      });
    });
  }    
}
```

But in fact, we also should use arrow function notation, which will keep the correct scope of the this:

```
createNew() {
    // the function () is replaced with arrow function
    describe('Create new' , () => {
      it('Clear input boxes', () => {
        this.tabClear(); // HERE the this.tabClear() is the answer
      });
    });
  }
```

see more details about arrow functions here:

- [TypeScript Arrow Function Tutorial](http://www.codebelt.com/typescript/arrow-function-typescript-tutorial/)

small cite:

> *“Arrow function expressions are a compact form of function expressions that omit the function keyword and have lexical scoping of this.”* Basically the Arrow Function helps you retain a certain scope automatically. If you look at the outputted code from the compiler, it just creates a var _this = this; and it is used inside the function.